# Refused to load the image 'http://192.xxx.x3000/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'"

Tags: android, ionic-framework

When I run an ionic app in Android Studio on a phone running android 5 no images are displayed and I get this message for each image:

```
Refused to connect to 'http://192.xxx.x.xxx:3000/promotions/0' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

On content-security-policy.com I found and tried the following:

```
Starter Policy

This policy allows images, scripts, AJAX, and CSS from the same origin, and does not allow any other resources to load (eg object, frame, media, etc). It is a good starting point for many sites.

default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';
```

But still no luck. In fact I have tried many permutations of the Content Security Policy all without success.
I get the same as using Android Studio when I use:

```
ionic build android
ionic run android
```

The images are stored on a JSON-server which runs ok and everything works fine on localhost on the computer.

Any pointers for solving this issue ? Thanks

Comment: try to add this meta in the head
  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ">`

Comment: Thanks very much. Put it as an answer and I will mark it as the answer to help others. I had to search for hours without success until now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add this meta in the head
  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ">`